# Clicking captcha iframe programmatically is not working

Tags: c#, browser, captcha

what am trying to do is click on `iframe` programmatically which looks like this

[image]

and the `html` code is:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf3v8wSAAAAABVuu8qFKDtsvc0ILPoyUBVRToA9" style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div>
        <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
            <iframe id="I0_1420487033543" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="" tabindex="0" vspace="0" name="I0_1420487033543" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6Lf3v8wSAAAAA…=http%3A%2F%2F&pfname=&rpctoken=24572959"></iframe>
        </div>
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none; " name="g-recaptcha-response" dir="ltr"></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
```

and what am trying to do is:

```
private void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Web.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                return;


            this.Web = sender as WebBrowser;


            var theElementCollection = Web.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");

            for (int i = 0; i < theElementCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlElement curElement = theElementCollection[i];

                if (curElement.Id != null && curElement.Id.StartsWith("I0_"))
                {
                    curElement.InvokeMember("click");

                }
            }
        }
```

but it's not working, how I can solve that?

Comment: Probably built-in browser security is blocking the click (the domains are different).

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: yes, the top level document should not be able to automate the contents of an iframe. But nonetheless, if this was possible then this captcha would be useless, the whole point of captchas is that you cannot automate them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve something similar to what you where looking for by using Selenium and the following code:

```
private static void verifySites(string username, string password)
{
     using (var ffox = new FirefoxDriver()
     {
         /// code to login once logged in
         var recaptcha = ffox.FindElementByTagName("iframe");
         recaptcha.Click();
     }
}
```